# How to remove unsafe contents of WYSIWYG editors before use it?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

How to remove unsafe contents of WYSIWYG editors  like **script** tags or **iframe** tags and **events** of other tags before use it?

```
<script>
// Dangerous contents
</script>

<iframe>
// bad web pages
</iframe>

<span onclick="javascript://do bad work here !!!">click me</span>
```

Comment: Why? If the code is coming from the editor then it is being entered by the user. If you are processing it with JS, then the only person who can be harmed is *that* user. You can't prevent a user from attacking themselves. If you block them there, then they can use another avenue (such as the browser's JavaScript console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to write such protection on your own.

Specially, you should NOT place the protection on the client side (javascript), but use instead a server side filtering like http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: I think it should say that you should _not_ place the protection on the client side.

Comment: @iman Other people's APIs should have server side protections as well. Relying only on client side protection is bad practice as this can be circumvented.

Comment: @Chris, yes you're right :-) 
iman even if you have to use client side protections, you should search for existing libraries.

Answer (score -1):

We can use a javascript function like this one to neutrilize

```
function neutralizeText(text) {
    var i,mtch=text.match(/(<[a-z]+\s+[^>]*\s+|<[a-z]+\s+)on[a-z]+(\s)*=(\b|\s|[^>])*>/gi);
    if(mtch!=null) {
        for(i=0;i<mtch.length;i++) {
            text=text.replace(mtch[i],mtch[i].replace(/\s+on[a-z]+(\s)*=/gi,' data-neutralized='));
        }
    }
    text=text.replace(/<script(\b|\s)[^>]*>(([ \t\r\n]|.)*?)<\/script>/ig,'');
    text=text.replace(/<iframe(\b|\s)[^>]*>(([ \t\r\n]|.)*?)<\/iframe>/ig,'');
    text=text.replace(/<object(\b|\s)[^>]*>(([ \t\r\n]|.)*?)<\/object>/ig,'');
    text=text.replace(/<\!\-\-(.*?)\-\->/g,'');
    text=text.replace(/<\!\-\-/g,'');
    return text;
}
```

but it is not enough and you **MUST** check it in server side. because javascript can be disabled in browsers.

Comment: this is a client side protection way